# How to use Obj-C Framework code in Swift Framework?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

How to use Obj-C Framework code in Swift Framework?
Is it possible or I need to mix them in a single Framework?
I have code for both Frameworks. I connect them manually without CocoaPods, Carthage or Swift Package Manager. Bridging header cannot be used inside of a Framework, only in App Target. Google says that I need to use modulemap file. In all examples I found they create their own modulemap files and put them near the Swift framework code. I tried to use both my own modulemap file and existing one inside ObjCFramework.framework/Modules. I use them by adding a path to the modulemap file to SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS build setting of my Swift Framework. I also tried to #import Obj-C Frameworks Ubrella Header to Swift Frameworks Ubrella Header with no luck. Of course I added the Obj-C Framework target to my Swift Framework target dependencies, the framework itself to Frameworks and Libraries and the path to it to Framework Search Paths. I didn't put anything to Header Search Paths to avoid "Include of non-modular header inside framework module", but that didn't help. CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES build setting doesn't help too. DEFINES_MODULE is set to YES.
Now I'm in endless loop of several errors:

- Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'ObjCFramework': '/Users/bond/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftFramework-aqidpocynynsvdgtrqwukanwqkxf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ObjCFramework.framework/Headers/View.h'
- Module 'ObjCFramework' was built in directory '/Users/bond/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftFramework-aqidpocynynsvdgtrqwukanwqkxf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ObjCFramework.framework' but now resides in directory '/Users/bond/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftFramework-aqidpocynynsvdgtrqwukanwqkxf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ObjCFramework.framework/Modules'
- No such module ObjCFramework
- underlying Objective-C module not found

Answer (score 0):

In brief this is described here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift, "Import Code Within a Framework Target" chapter.

If the Defines Module setting is turned on in your framework target, modern Xcode puts Modules folder in the framework, with Swift versions of all you ObjC public interfaces, making ObjC stuff available either for external Swift code that links your framework or Swift code of the framework itself.
This does not depend on whether your framework target contains any swift code.

Just add you ObjC header to framework target, mark it as Public in "Target membership", include in framework Umbrella header and build.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.